# Python 2.7 inheritance from metaclasses

Tags: python, metaclass

I've got a toy python example where defining an inline metaclass as a function behaves differently than defining it as a class, and I'm trying to understand why:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __metaclass__(name, bases, nmspc):
...         cls = type(name, bases, nmspc)
...         def __init__(self, field, *args, **kwargs):
...             print "making " + field
...             super(cls, self).__init__()
...         cls.__init__ = __init__
...         return cls
... 
>>> t = Test('lol')
making lol
>>> class Test2(Test): pass
... 
>>> t = Test2('lol')
making lol
```

Versus:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...      class __metaclass__(type):
...              def __init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc):
...                      type.__init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc)
...                      def __init__(self, field, *args, **kwargs):
...                              print "making " + field
...                              super(cls, self).__init__()
...                      cls.__init__ = __init__
... 
>>> t = Test('lol')
making lol
>>> class Test2(Test): pass
... 
>>> t2 = Test2('lol')
making lol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So, what exactly is different between defining a class vs defining a function? They both end up returning a class through slightly different ways, since the modified cls.__init__ gets inherited one way but not the other.

I also checked similar construction by making a function and class declaration outside, and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Your question appears to be *"why do different things behave differently?"* - could you clarify what you were expecting?

Comment: I was expecting the child classes of both definitions of \_\_metaclass\_\_ to get the same \_\_init\_\_ method.

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully read the [documentation on metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__), you'll note that when Python checks for an inherited metaclass, it doesn't look at the `__metaclass__` attribute of the base class, it looks for its `__class__` or type (because in general, the metaclass of a class is its class). (You can see the C code implementing this behavior in [the `build_class` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5c55a7bfec0c/Python/ceval.c#l4619).)

Your function version calls `type` to construct the class, and then patches it afterwards. But the class's class is still set to `type`, because that's where it was actually built.

Your class version, on the other hand, subclasses `type` and itself becomes the `__class__` of the created class.

You can see this difference (here I've named your function version `TestF` and your class version `TestC`, and imported them both from a module named `mc`):

```
In [7]: TestC.__class__
Out[7]: mc.__metaclass__

In [8]: TestF.__class__
Out[8]: type

In [9]: type(TestC)
Out[9]: mc.__metaclass__

In [10]: type(TestF)
Out[10]: type
```

Because of this difference, when you inherit from `TestC`, `__metaclass__` is used as the metaclass for the new subclass, whereas when you inherit from `TestF`, `type` is used.

Why does this result in the observed difference? Because in the `TestF` case, since no custom metaclass is applied to the creation of the subclass, the subclass doesn't get a modified `__init__` method applied. So the `__init__` method called is still `TestF.__init__()`, and when it calls `super(cls, self).__init__()` it is calling `object.__init__()` which takes no arguments, and this works fine.

But in the `TestC` case, the metaclass is used again when you create the subclass. (You can observe this difference if you insert a `print` statement right before the `cls.__init__ = __init__` line of each version.) So the subclass gets its own custom `__init__` method. So in this case, when it calls `super(cls, self).__init__()`, it is calling `TestC.__init__()`, which (itself having been created by the metaclass), takes the required argument `field`, which you are not passing. And thus you get the `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` error.